# a proof about recurrent state in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, statistical-mechanics

It's about the definition of a recurrent state. I think there might be something wrong in book **neural network and learning machines**. it is said as following.

> Suppose a Markov chain starts in state i. State i is said to be a
>   recurrent state if the Markov chain returns to state i with
>   probability 1; that is,
>  pi =P(ever returning to state i) =1 
>   If the probability pi is less than 1, state iis said to be a
>   transientstate (Leon-Garcia, 1994). If the Markov chain starts in a
>   recurrent state, that state reoccurs an infinite number of times. If
>   it starts in a transient state, that state reoccurs only a finite
>   number of times, which may be explained as follows: ***We may view the
>   reoccurrence of state i as a Bernoulli trial with a probability of
>   success equal to pi .The number of returns is thus a geometric random
>   variable with a mean of (1 - 1/pi).*** If pi < 1, it follows that the
>   number of an infinite number of successes is zero.Therefore, a
>   transient state does not reoccur after some finite number of returns.

You can see those italics. I can't figure out what kind of the Bernoulli trail it is. Why it has a mean of (1 - 1/pi), which indicates that when pi < 1, the mean is less than zero. Maybe it is a typo, maybe it should have meant to be (1/pi - 1). But it still seems make no sense. I mean if you want to prove that the probability for a transient state to reoccur an infinite number of times is zero, you can just use the limitation of pi^n is zero when pi<1. It has really confused me for quite a long time. Anyone has any advice here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes the mean number of returns to $i$ starting from $i$ is $\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}$, the probability of at least $n$ returns to $i$ starting from $i$ is $p_i^n$, and the fact that $p_i^n\to0$ when $p_i<1$ suffices to prove that the number of returns to $i$ starting from $i$ is almost surely finite. (Use another reference to learn the basics of Markov chains theory, *Markov chains* by Norris is on the web, easy to read, and rigorous.)